# Why is Akka Kill not terminating this supervisor and its children?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I have a supervisor below that creates child processes using the default Play! 2.2 `Akka.system`. When I attempt to instantaneously kill the supervisor, nothing happens and it keeps processing.

```
class ImportSupervisor extends Actor {

        import akka.actor.AllForOneStrategy
        import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._
        import scala.concurrent.duration._

        val log = Logging(context.system, this)
        override val supervisorStrategy =
          AllForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 hour) {
            case e: Exception => Stop
          }

        override def preStart() {
          Logger.info("supervisor starting up at "+self.toString)
        }

        def receive = {
          case p: Props => context.actorOf(p)
        }
      }
```

Below is the code I'm using to kill the supervisor which has about 1,000 children:

`Akka.system.actorSelection("akka://application/user/"+actorName) ! Kill`

I can verify I am getting the ActorPath correct, but the problem is the `Kill` does not take effect instantaneously. I've tried the same with `Stop`. What am I doing wrong? Is it wrong to assume that it would shut down instantly?

Comment: By design, Akka never guarantees that anything will be executed "immediately", or even after a specific delay. For example, when scheduling a task to be executed in "2 seconds" you should not assume that it will effectively run in exactly 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it wrong to assume that it would shut down instantly?

Yes.

The `Kill` message will be enqueued in the actor's mailbox just like any other message.  If there are other messages ahead of it, other the actor is busy processing another message, the `Kill` message will have to wait.

All of this is explained in the documentation:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/scala/actors.html#Stopping_actors

Comment: that's what  thought, but what about `Stop` as mentioned in the question? I read that same doc and did I misunderstand that `Stop` would do the same? Or do I need to set up a supervisor of the supervisor to do that?

Comment: You can't stop actors immediately in Akka.  As the docs say, "The actual termination of the actor is performed asynchronously, i.e. `stop` may return before the actor is stopped."  The difference between `Kill` and `ActorRef.stop` is just in how the now-dead actor's supervisor deals with it.

Comment: I realized the methodology for accomplishing this is not to rely on the Actor or Supervisor itself, but instead create a specific ActorSystem for the tasks. This way if an immediate shutdown is needed, you can call `actorSystem.shutdown()`.

Comment: That is a bad idea. ActorSystems are heavyweight and you should rarely create more than one. And `ActorSystem.shutdown` is still asynchronous.

Comment: That is true, luckily for my particular task it's not for production use. Instead I'm handling a large streaming operation. And at some point I need to terminate the process to analyze the data I've streamed (and recover the CPU). You're totally right though.